# html js Adding child nodes to div stops working after about 2000 nodes. What is the limiting factor

Tags: javascript, html

I have a message monitor, that adds a new child node to a div each time a new message is received on the serial port. 
    51,32,52,58,00,00,ff Set volume to 58% on channel 1 
    51,32,01,00,00.00,05 Output volume/level on channel 3 is 14%
    etc.

using this js to add the lines to the monitor div

```
function messageReceived(text, id, channel)     
{     
 var newNode = document.createElement('p');       
 newNode.className ="mdata";    
 newNode.innerHTML = text + '<br/>';
 document.getElementById("messdiv").appendChild( newNode );
 var textarea = document.getElementById('dali_monitor');
 textarea.scrollTop = textarea.scrollHeight;       
};
```

After ~2hours and ~2000 messages they are not being added to the div anymore.
There are more messages, they can be seen in another page hooked to the same socket.

I do mean to, some latter date, add some way to take the oldest messages off and keep them somewhere to be displayed through some user action.

Where should I start looking for the cause and trigger for this, is there a  "Too many children ...something.. " event?

Trying to reproduce this problem and of cause it is not having any problems. Seems that there is something else going on, as the last 2 days it hasn't faulted at all.
I'm up to 8532 child nodes and still counting, 28 Hours of messages. 
I'm suspecting something to do with Windows / Ethernet / Power Saving somewhere that caused at least 2 occasions where the page wasn't updating.